# why salt minion ignoring /etc/salt/minion.d/*

Tags: salt-stack

My /etc/salt/minion only has the line:

```
default_include: minion.d/*.conf
```

I wrote a very simple minion.d configuration:
cat /etc/salt/minion.d/saltminion

```
master: 123.123.xxx.xxx
id: test2
```

salt-minion -l debug

```
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[INFO    ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: test1
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/minion
[INFO    ] Setting up the Salt Minion "test1"
[DEBUG   ] Created pidfile: /var/run/salt-minion.pid
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] The `lspci` binary is not available on the system. GPU grains will not be available.
[DEBUG   ] Attempting to authenticate with the Salt Master at 92.242.xxx.xxx
```

minion.d is completely ignored and I don't know where this 92.242.xxx.xxx ip is coming from, It looks like a major security hole to me. 
Version: salt-minion 2014.1.13+ds-3

Would someone shed some lights here? please. Thanks

Comment: Surely your /etc/salt/minion.d/saltminion should end with .conf ,as you specified in  /etc/salt/minion ?

Comment: if this is not the issue - have you reload the minion service after creating the file? edit - forget about it - just realized that this is minions log and not salt-call output... :)

Comment: oh gosh, that slipt pretty bad.. sorry. I've got too much used to work with cron.d/* . Anyways, I'm posting a second question related to salt-cp. Thanks nos.

Comment: Hey Martin how did you end up your fix for the question you posted. Could you please share the steps. Though this is late comment! :)

Comment: @PavanDevarakonda I think @nos was right. In that case I think I renamed `saltminion` to `saltminon.conf`. See if that works.